# Reinforcement Learning Algorithm stuck in infinite loop when choosing an infeasible action

Tags: infinite-loop, reinforcement-learning, agent

I wrote a gym environment and i am training this gym environment using the DQN agent from stable-baselines.

**What my environment dose**:

- action : int == 1, ..., n   --> Add an order n (containing (1 <= x <= 10) items) to a list (lets call it "item_list").
- action == 0           --> Close the item_list (no further items can be added).

**So whats the problem?**

There is a max number of items allowed in the item_list. This means if the item_list is almost full and the agent chooses action >= 1 --> The capacity of the "item_list is exceeded. Thus it is an infeasable action.

**What happens in this case?**

In that case the order will not be added to "item_list" and the Agent receaves a negative reward. The problem is that the Observation of my agent wont chainge at all. This will lead to my Agent choosing the same action over and over again.

**When does it become a problem?**

During training it does not matter that much. The Agent will learn to avoid choosing an action like this and exploration will always get the agent out of this loop after a while. Though, when i want to use the trained agent there will be no exploration. One "bad" action would be enough to send this agent into a infinite loop of choosing an order that does not fit into the item_list.

**What kind of answer am I looking for?**

Is there a way of dealing with those infinite loops exept form hardcoding a lot of exceptions? If the capacity of item_list ist exeeded it would be easy to hardcode that the list should be closed the way it ist. Though the same infinite loop can appear if the item_list is empty and the Agent chooses action == 0 (closing an empty list). There are many other cases where this problem can occure. Is there a smart solution for this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Two general approaches to consider:

First, do not allow illegal actions. When your agent outputs a distribution over actions, multiply it by indicator vector that zeroes out illegal actions. Then sample an action.

Second, after an illegal action terminate the episode with a negative reward. You already assign a negative reward for illegal action, additionally terminate the episode, so that there is no infinite loop.

I would go for the first one.

Edit: see this question as well: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/how-should-i-handle-invalid-actions-when-using-reinforce